# How to fix ECONREST at TLSWrap.onStreamRead

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I am trying to split an array and then loop though them to use a GET request for an API any when i try to create the chucks and loop through them i receive this error

```
{ Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:111:27) errno: 'ECONNRESET', code: 'ECONNRESET', syscall: 'read' }
```

```
function chunck(array, size){
  const chunked_arr = [];
  let index = 0;
  while(index < array.length){
    chunked_arr.push(array.slice(index, size + index));
    index += size;
  }
  return request('https://api.census.gov/data/2016/acs/acs5?get=NAME' + chunked_arr + '&for=state:*&key=' + censusAPI
  , { json: true }, (err, res, body) => {
    if (err) { return console.log(err); }
    return console.log(body);
  });
}

for(i = 0; i < arrayVars.length; i++){
  resSet.push(arrayVars[i][0]);
}

Promise.all(resSet).then(function(base){
  chunck(base, 1);
}).catch(function(err){
  console.info(err);
});
```